# 500 Internal Server Error Express + Axios

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, proxy, http-status-code-500

When I make a fetch request, I get a 500 error, but when I just return an array of values, everything goes well, please tell me.

My server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors"); 
const CoinGecko = require("coingecko-api")
const app = express();

const CoinGeckoClient = new CoinGecko();
app.use(cors())
app.get('/coins',  (req, res) => {
        await axios.get<ICoin[]>(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?`, {params: {
            vs_currency: "usd",  
            per_page: 100, 
            page: 1,  
         }})
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            res.json(response.data);
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
       
})

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 5000');
  });
```

My fetch request:

```
export default class CoinsService {
static async getAll(page ) {
    let response: ICoin[] = []
    await axios.get('/coins').then(data => console.log(data)
    )
}
}
```

I tried to output the exact error but got the same message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PM3J.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS026.png)

Comment: remove ```await``` if you handle the promise in the traditional way.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi It's an async function that I forgot to remove when copying the code, it doesn't work without it either.

Comment: I went to localhost:5000 and got an error `Cannot GET /` and `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0):

1. as montionned in @Vahid Alimohamadi comment you don't need `await` if you you are using [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
2. most probably the error is from this line :

```
await axios.get<ICoin[]>
```

here you are expecting the `Response` type to be `ICoin[]` which is probably not, replace it with

```
axios.get<any>
```

if the error disappears then you have understood the reason.

**but this is only for debugging, REMEMBER:**

> using the `any` type is not recommanded

Comment: I went to localhost:5000 and got an error `Cannot GET /` and `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: this is a different error

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, it was my carelessness.

I used

```
app.get('/coins', async (req, res) => {
         CoinGeckoClient.coins.markets({
            vs_currency: 'usd',
            per_page: 100,
            page: page,
            sparkline: false
        }).then((response) => {
            res.json(response.data);
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

Replacing this option, I got the data.

```
app.get('/coins', async (req, res) => {
        await axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?', {
          params: {
                vs_currency: "usd", // Convert prices to USD
                per_page: 100, // Get top 100 coins
                page: 1, // Get first page
             }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            res.json(response.data);
          }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

I would like to know why I could not use the 1st option?

Comment: because you don't return the promise in the first one.
```return CoinGeckoClient.coins.markets...```